# How to ignore error and build successfully by using msbuild command?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, command-line, msbuild

I have tried these command to ignore the error messages by using msbuild command, but it doesn't work.

```
msbuild /property:ContinueOnError=true E:...../xxx.sln
```

I got error messages like

> GRGVTMWorkflowImp.cs(52,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'GrgCreateFunctionAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a
> using directive or an assembly reference?)
> [E:\Fortify_Scan\src\AP1\VTM\20220607\20220601\GRGVTMBusinessService\GRGVTMWorkflow\GRGVTMWorkflow.csproj]
> GRGVTMWorkflowImp.cs(36,6): error CS0246: The type or namespace name
> 'GrgComponent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

I know what these error messages means but I still want the project can be build successfully.

Is it possible to ignore those error messages by using msbuild command or any other way to do it?

Comment: *"ContinueOnError=ture"*. What is "ture" when it's at home? ;-)

Comment: sorry, it is a typo, fixed

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#attributes) I get the impression that `ContinueOnError` is purely a property for MSBuild Tasks. While it is true that you're entering the build process via MSBuild, at some point the compiler `csc.exe` will be called.
I didn't find any information whether the compiler also supports this property. But I doubt it, because what should the compiler do with a project that is obviously corrupt (missing dependencies)? My assumption and expectation - fail fast.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [MSBuild command line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022) we can see that “-property:name=value” just can set or override the specified project-level properties but [ContinueOnError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#attributes) is an attribute of task, so it doesn’t work to change the value of ContinueOnError.

If you want to change the value of ContinueOnError you can write a task to define ContinueOnError=true such as:

```
<Task 
    Parameter1="Value1" ContinueOnError=" true ">
</Task>
```

or use Directory.Build.targets to [customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022).